# Learning development with Force platform. Any good books?

Tags: apex, soql, force.com

I'm a bit familiar with Java and SQL, any good books to get on coding in Apex for salesforce?

Comment: Not a book, but the Dev 501 classes recorded from a few years ago, but still mostly relevant, are available for _free_ in the iTunes store. Dev 401 is there as well, but there's no programming in 401.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I did watch some of Dev 401 series, now that I'm actually coding, I can probably go ahead with Dev 501.

Comment: Development with the Force.com Platform - this one has good reviews on Amazon...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Advanced Apex Programming for Salesforce.com and Force.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1936754053) is a great book.  The author is very knowledgeable and the book is well-written.  I think it is a great read for all Apex skill levels - beginner to expert.

Comment: I would like to add "salesforce handbook"  by Jeff Douglas and Wes nolte to this.

Answer (score 5):

You are going to want to start with [Force.com Fundamentals](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force_Platform_Fundamentals). This doesn't focus on Apex/Visualforce, but rather than base platform. Coding in Salesforce doesn't happen right away. You need to have a great understanding of the platform before you jump into the code, otherwise you will code things that you really don't need to code.

Once you do that, you can begin to [learn Apex using Salesforce's provider instructional material](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_intro_learning_apex.htm). Specifically, the [Force.com Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook/index.htm), [Apex Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/index.htm), and then supplimenting that with the [Cookbook](http://developer.force.com/cookbook).

As well as learning Apex, take some time to figure out [Visualforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce) as well, the two go hand in hand.

For reference:

- [Visualforce Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm)
- [Apex Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm)

Just as a final note, check out [Clean Code by Robert Martin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882). It has nothing to do with Apex/Visualforce, but it is a great read for any programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Its good that you have basic understanding of Java etc, It would definately help a lot.
Also try learning a bit of HTML, CSS, Javscript, jquery etc as they are used in VF pages. To code on Salesforce, the Admin knowledge of Platform is also beneficial.

All the Best

Answer (score 0):

Now there are lots of self paced good courses available online which can be taken at your own comfort. I dont know if I am allowed to paste the course link here but you should surely check out and search on Websites like  Udemy.com , Pluralsight etc . Also if you do some online search you may also find discounted or even free coupon for them as well.

Edited: Skillfeed has been sadly closed. Also wanted to add a new platform http://courses.getskillsfast.com  because the courses are very comprehensive and this is the only website which has end to end salesforce Integration course covering both SOAP and REST .